# Prevent Non-Admin User Account from Installing Programs -Windows 10

Tags: windows, group-policy, administration, system-administration

This simple thing is driving me nuts. I need to block my employees who have a local/non administrator account on their windows 10 laptop, from being able to install any application or program. I tried the GPO route

Computer Configurations > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Installer --- Turn off Windows Installer

I even changed local security policy settings for User Account Control.

Even created a registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun

It just doesnt seem to work. Zoom app simply installs without prompting for admin password.

Ideal behaviour should be --- when a non admin user tries to install the application --- it should prompt for administrator credentials.

PLEASE ADVISE/HELP.

Comment: The Zoom installer is local to that individual user—not a global install. You would have to prevent users from writing  to their own profile or implement app locker (or an equivalent).

Comment: User-space installs are just not blockable. an installer is just an application, so it doesn't need to use a service or anything. if the user has write access to all the things they need to write, you will need an intelligent layer (like endpoint security product) to control their actions. static system configuration won't do it, if you can't deny write.